# BigInsights v3.0.0.2 Monitoring fails to write into HBase

Tags: hbase, biginsights

recently i've encountered a problem: after installation of BigInsights all of my services works fine, except for monitoring which fails with error "No agents can write HBase tables successfully" even though there was no errors during the installation process. Is there anything i could have forgotten about/any advices what to check or do in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Start hbase shell and list tables. See if the Monitor tables are created. If not  run this...

$BIGINSIGHTS_HOME/hbase/bin/hbase shell < $BIGINSIGHTS_HOME/monitoring/etc/chukwa/hbase.schema